# Value not getting from form while using javascript validation

Tags: javascript, html

When form validating, I'm not able to get the value from textbox. Instead I'm getting error like this -

HTML:

```
<div class="div3-1" style="display:none" id="sub1">
    <form name="registrationform" action="" method="POST" id="form1" onSubmit="javascript:return formValidate()">
        <ul id="ulli">
            <li>
                <label>Name: </label>
                <input type="text" name="name">
            </li>

            <li>
                <label>Username: </label>
                <input type="text" name="username">
            </li>

            <li>
                <label>Email: </label>
                <input type="text" name="email">
            </li>

            <li>
                <label>Password: </label>
                <input type="text" name="password">
            </li>

            <li>
                <label>Confirm Password: </label>
                <input type="text" name="confpassword">
            </li>

            <li>
                <label>Sex: </label>
                <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male">
                <label for="Male">Male</label>
                <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female">
                <label for="Female">Female</label>
            </li>

            <li>
                <label>Date of Birth: </label>
                <input type="text" name="dob">
            </li>

            <li>
                <label>Phone Number: </label>
                <input type="text" name="phno">
            </li>

            <li>
                <label>Country: </label>
                <input type="text" name="country">
            </li>

            <li>
                <label>State: </label>
                <input type="text" name="state">
            </li>

            <li>
                <label>City: </label>
                <input type="text" name="city">
            </li>

            <li>
                <label>Pincode: </label>
                <input type="text" name="pincode">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </label>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </form>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function formValidate() {
    var name1 = document.getElementById("name").value;

    if (name1 == "") {
        alert("name field is empty");
    } else if (name1.length < 4) {
        alert("length field is empty");
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: I guess there is no issue with your JS code, i am very sure issue is in your HTML.

Comment: There is no `id` on the element, either id on them and use `getElementById` or use `querySelector('[name="name"]')` or `getElementsByName('name')[0]`

Comment: yeah..i got the area where i was wrong, i didn't use id field..Thanks alot Tushar..

Comment: In addition to the JS validation, I'd also suggest to use `pattern` attribute on the element. Ex. `<input type="text" name="name" pattern="[a-zA-Z]{4,}" />`

Comment: ok sure thanks alot..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your input has the id="name" ?

if it's like this then it should work!

```
<input type="text" name="inputname" id="name">
```

You are looking for your input element by "id" (getElementById), the name property of the input is different from the id property.

Working example:

```js
function formValidate() {
    var name1 = document.getElementById("name").value;

    if (name1 == "") {
        alert("name field is empty");
    } else if (name1.length < 4) {
        alert("length field is empty");
    }
}
```

```html
 <form>
  First name: <input type="text" name="inputname" id="name"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="formValidate()">
</form>
```

Comment: <input type="text" name="name">

Comment: also using form submit - <form name="registrationform" action="" method="POST" id="form1" onSubmit="javascript:return formValidate()">

Comment: just change `<input type="text" name="name">` to `<input type="text" name="name" id="name">`

Comment: if this resolved your question please check it as the resolving answer!

Comment: Glad this could help!

Answer (score 0):

Check this, it might help you identify difference and solve your issue.

**UPDATE:
Looking to your HTML, i can see is there is no `id="name"` for your Name Text-field. So add `id="name"` to it. Your code will work like charm after.**

**Replace this:**

```
<li>
    <label>Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
</li>
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
<input type="button" onclick="formValidate()" value="validate" />
```

**JS**

```
function formValidate() {

    var name1 = document.getElementById("name").value;

    if (name1 == "") {
        alert("name field is empty");

    } else if (name1.length < 4) {
        alert("length field is empty");

    }
}
```

**<kbd>[Working : Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/divy3993/vsqewnh5/)</kbd>**